# JS add class to individual html items instead of all of them on click

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the .category-items to change color when I click on them. I have gotten to the point of targetting the items and putting in a for loop which my intent was to be able to recognize all the elements with that class name and then individually click and have them each change color. Instead, all of the items light up at once.

```js
function categoryClicked(){
    var categoryItem = document.querySelectorAll('.category-item');
    for(var i = 0; i < categoryItem.length; i++){
        categoryItem[i].classList.add('category-active');
    }
}
```

```css
.menu-categories{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
.category-item{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    border-radius: 12px;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.category-item:hover{
    background: #EBF9FC;
}
.category-name{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #222;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.category-item.category-active{
    background: #FF6347 !important;
}
.category-item.category-active .category-name{
    color: #f6f6f6 !important;
}
```

```html
                <div class="menu-categories">
                    <div onclick="categoryClicked()" class="category-item">
                        <h4 class="category-name">Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div onclick="categoryClicked()" class="category-item">
                        <h4 class="category-name">Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div onclick="categoryClicked()" class="category-item">
                        <h4 class="category-name">Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div onclick="categoryClicked()" class="category-item">
                        <h4 class="category-name">Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div onclick="categoryClicked()" class="category-item">
                        <h4 class="category-name">Item</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass element "this" while calling the function and you can toggle the element's class like this.

```js
function categoryClicked(el){

        el.classList.toggle('category-active');
   
}
```

```css
.menu-categories{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
.category-item{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    border-radius: 12px;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.category-item:hover{
    background: #EBF9FC;
}
.category-name{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #222;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.category-item.category-active{
    background: #FF6347 !important;
}
.category-item.category-active .category-name{
    color: #f6f6f6 !important;
}
```

```html
                <div class="menu-categories">
                    <div onclick="categoryClicked(this)" class="category-item">
                        <h4 class="category-name">Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div onclick="categoryClicked(this)" class="category-item">
                        <h4 class="category-name">Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div onclick="categoryClicked(this)" class="category-item">
                        <h4 class="category-name">Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div onclick="categoryClicked(this)" class="category-item">
                        <h4 class="category-name">Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div onclick="categoryClicked(this)" class="category-item">
                        <h4 class="category-name">Item</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
```